# How do I connect to a terminal on a different router?

Tags: router, http

[image: Flow]

I am hosting a http server on `Terminal 2` which is on `Router 1` and I want to connect to `Terminal 4` which is on `Router 2`. I know the IP address of Routers and the LAN addresses of the terminals.

If both terminals are under the same router then I can simply use the LAN addresses to send the HTTP requests but I dont know what to do if the Routers are different.

Both routers have internet connection. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to know the capabilities of the routers without their model. However, there are generally two options:

- Set up a VPN between the sites with routing between the internal networks.
- Port forward necessary ports to the *term4* on *router2* and access using the external IP. This way you won't be able to access both *term3* and *term4*.

Comment: I am using smartphone mobile hotspots.

Comment: Then this is probably impossible. You would need an external VPN server somewhere with a static IP and access from both the smartphones. Each client, rather than the phones, should connect to that VPN server.

Comment: I downloaded [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elixsr.portforwarder&rdid=com.elixsr.portforwarder). It didnt work for me but I will leave it here for the reference of others.

Comment: Some mobile operators have their clients behind a NAT to save public IP addresses. For most this is fine, since mobile connentions aren't designed for hosting any servers.